# getWidth() and getHeight() always returning 0. Custom view

Tags: android, android-view

In a Fragment, I am inflating a Layout with multiple child View. I need to get the dimensions (width and height) of one of them which is a custom view.

Inside the custom view class I can do it easily. But if I try to do it from the fragment I always get 0 as dimensions.

```
 public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    View culoide = view.findViewWithTag(DRAW_AREA_TAG);
    Log.d("event", "culoide is: "+culoide.getWidth()); // always 0
}
```

I figure that onViewCreated should be the right place to get it, but well this happens. I tried before super.onViewCreated, in debug it looks like 'findViewWithTag' finds the right view, tried with api 7 v4 support only.

Any help?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You must wait until after the first measure and layout in order to get nonzero values for `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`. You can do this with a [`ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayouListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html)

```
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle saved) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, saved);
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
              view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
              view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

            // get width and height of the view
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks :) ; removeGlobalOnLayoutListener is today already deprecated ; but that's already a different issue

Comment: The deprecated method calls through to the new one (and in fact I don't know if it was worth deprecating just because of the name), but I've edited my code anyway.

Comment: Or just override `onSizeChanged()`.

Comment: In my case I want to use the getWidth() to adjust some padding/margin. I cannot override onSizeChanged() since it is called during layout and changes to padding/margin would not be persisted. The OnGlobalLayoutListener fires when layout is finished, no problems there.

Comment: Remember to set mView=null in onDestroyView().

Comment: You have to call `view.getViewTreeObserver()` instead of saving `observer` as variable

Answer (score 6):

My preferred method is to add an `OnLayoutChangeListener` to the view that you want to track itself

```
CustomView customView = ...

customView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        // Make changes
    }
});
```

You can remove the listener in the callback if you only want the initial layout.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`, `View.post(Runnable action)` or `onWindowFocusChanged()` isn't the best solution. This [article](https://cheesecakelabs.com/blog/understanding-android-views-dimensions-set/) (note: I am the author of this article) explains why and provides a working solution using `doOnLayout` kotlin extension, which is based on `View.OnLayoutChangeListener`. If you want it in Java, in the article there's a link to `doOnLayout` source code, it's very simple and you can do something similar in Java too.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait until the [onSizeChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method is called before you can reliably determine the View size.

> This is called during layout when the size of this view has changed.
>   If you were just added to the view hierarchy, you're called with the
>   old values of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

`culoide.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);`

first, then try `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`

Answer (score 0):

Try checking in onWindowFocusChanged and it should have valid values:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) { }
```

I had a similar issue where I needed to get width and height of a widget and this was the function in which I could guarantee the widget reported it's correct size.

Answer (score 0):

this is a real pain especially because you expected with a name like onViewCreated in fragments lifecycle that the view is ready.  for me get the [fragment view](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#getView()) itself like this:

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)   
     getView()?.let{
                  it.doOnLayout{// do your UI work here }
                   }
    }
```

this ensures the fragments getView has actually had one layout pass already.