# getHeight() of PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I have multiple `FrameLayout` inside a `ScrollView`. In one of the `FrameLayout` I'm loading a `PreferenceFragment`. Now I need to set the height of the `FrameLayout` to the height of the `PreferenceFragment` to avoid nested scrolling (the `PrefrenceFragment` is scrollable too).

How can I get the height of the `PreferenceFragment`?

I tried to override `onCreateView()` in the `PreferenceFragment` class, and call `View.getHeight()`, but its just returning 0.

Setting the `FrameLayout` to `wrap_content`, isn't working as well, its just taking the space of a single preference then...

**edit:**
I tried now to get the height by using `addOnGlobalLayoutListener()` but the returned value is just the displayed height, not the full height of the `PreferenceFragment`. So I'm just getting the height of one preference for `wrap_content` or e.g. 300 if I set the height of the `FrameLayout` to 300 in the xml. I need the full height of all preferences (visibile and not).

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater paramLayoutInflater, ViewGroup paramViewGroup, Bundle paramBundle)
{
  final View v = super.onCreateView(paramLayoutInflater, paramViewGroup, paramBundle);
  if (v != null) {
    ViewTreeObserver vto = v.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
      Log.d("TEST", "Height = " + v.getHeight() + " Width = " + v.getWidth());
      ViewTreeObserver obs = v.getViewTreeObserver();
      obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
    });
  }
  return v;
}
```

Comment: Check this stackoverflow.com/questions/12352920/measure-view-in-fragment. You need to wait till the view is layed and then measure.

Comment: not sure but look at this one ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925317/getwidth-and-getheight-always-returning-0-custom-view and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170915/getheight-returns-0-for-all-android-ui-objects

Comment: @Raghunandan and Nik: thanks for your links, unfortunately its still not working for me, see the edit

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for WindowFocusChange in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus)
        //LAYOUT FRAGMENT NOW
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            height = parentLayout.getheight();// the root layout of the fragment
            //TODO: 
        }
    }, 200);
```