# Height and width must be greater than 0?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create whiteboard type application using fragments. But, I am having problem in height whenever fragments called height is always zero but this code is working perfect in activities. When onSizeChanged function called height is always 0. Please see the code and error below

getting this error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          Process: com.example.ebmacs.vickyy.kids, PID: 5781
          java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
              at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:829)
              at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:808)
              at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:775)
              at com.example.ebmacs.vickyy.kids.Classes.PaintView.onSizeChanged(PaintView.java:82)
              at android.view.View.sizeChange(View.java:16748)
              at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:16710)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16627)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
              at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1525)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1732)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1497)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
              at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1
```

this is code where i get error

```
 @Override
public void onSizeChanged(int widthContentView, int heightContentView, int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {
    super.onSizeChanged(widthContentView, heightContentView, oldWidth, oldHeight);
    this.bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthContentView,heightContentView, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    this.canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: [Check this link out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16925529/6544105)

Comment: its not working my class is extends to view